# Scrape after login, and button click

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, request

I am trying to scrape a website with selenium, and it requires a login, then you must click on your profile.

I have figured that out but I can't seem to scrape the data on the page. Here is what I've tried and my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/kingpey/Desktop/chromedriver")
site = driver.get("site")
ID = driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("usernameee")
Password = driver.find_element_by_id("Password").send_keys("pass")
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='page']/div[@id='main']/div[1]/form[@id='loginform']/div[@id='login']/div[@class='widgetbdy']/table[@class='txtin3']/tbody/tr[5]/td/input[@id='LoginButton']")
button.click()
time.sleep(1)
arrow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='page']/div[@id='main']/div[1]/div[@id='StudentBanner']/table[@id='stuBannerContainerTable']/tbody/tr/td/table[@id='stuBannerTable']/tbody/tr[@id='id']/td[3]")
arrow.click()
time.sleep(5)
```

The arrow is a button I have to click to get to the main page.

Everything above works fine. Now how would I scrape this:

```
<td align="center" valign="top" class="xh-highlight">I NEED THIS</td>
```

I want to get the "I NEED THIS" in the code above. The page has many of these in a table, and I wish to get all of them.

Comment: Anybody have any idea what to do?

Comment: share 5-6 lines of html code or url of webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IWebElement element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("// put your xpath here"));
```

`element.Text` will return the innerText of this element, eg. "I NEED THIS".

Comment: Thank you! worked! now when I switch to PhantomJS though, I get an error about the xpaths? ANY idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hello! Can you share to code in your PhantomJS? Thanks!